# Bullet disappearing if \visible used as first token of an \item

Tags: beamer

When using the Beamer command `visible` within an `itemize` environment, I noticed that sometimes the command makes the bullets disappear as well. In the example provided below, the bullet point on the fourth line is hidden along with the text next to it. I didn't expect this - how can I change this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{%
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item first
      \pause
      \item second
      \pause
      \item \only<3->{third} word jumping around -- not nice
      \pause
      \item \visible<4->{fourth} entry makes the bullet disappear -- why?
      \pause
      \item Does not happen unless the \visible<5->{appearing} word is at the beginning of the line. 
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It might be a bug. As a workaround, use `\item \leavevmode \visible<4->{...}`, as in:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{%
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item first
      \pause
      \item second
      \pause
      \item \only<3->{third} word jumping around -- not nice
      \pause
      \item \leavevmode \visible<4->{fourth} entry makes the bullet disappear -- why?
      \pause
      \item Does not happen unless the \visible<5->{appearing} word is at the beginning of the line. 
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How does it work? Well, the `\visible` is not at the beginning of the line anymore, there's `\leavevmode` in front of it :-)

Comment: similarly `\hspace{0pt}` etc. anything cools down TeX at the start of the line works. In the third scan it doesn't see an `\item`

Comment: @percusse Seems that it's almost the same: `\leavevmode: macro:->\unhbox \voidb@x` :)